# Edting Homepage text cannot find in homepage

Tags: homepage

Am not able to find the text in homepage to edit. When I go to Appearance > Customize it shows that " Home page 1 " is selected as per the picture attached. but when I go to all pages and select "Home Page 1" it come as blank(Please see the picture)
Please let me know where can I find it.

Regards,
Dillip S[image: Appearance-customize][image: Pages-home page 1[![][2]]][3]

Comment: Which theme are you using? your questions is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

it's seems that your home is using a theme features, so if you can tell us your theme we may give clear instructions on how you can edit the homepage. in the meanwhile, you can try these :

1) When you edit the home page 1 check in the right panel the **template** used, it will give you an idea about what template is used and it may help you identify how the content is managed

2) In all the pages, check if there is some pages that have as **parent page** the home page 1. Maybe the content is inside theses pages and the home page 1 is only displaying it

3) Check carefully your themes options maybe the content of home page is managed there

4) If you are using a premium theme, check the documentation which is always available with the package you download. You may find there instructions on how you edit the home page content.

Hope this will help you.